Linking between 2 legitimate websites
My friend has 2 legitimate businesses, the first and eco-friendly consulting, the second an eco-friendly product she developed independently and much later.
She has links in the bios of both websites referring to her other ventures because they are natural mentions given her commitment to the environment. They are different ventures so they will remain different websites. And, as she blogs on both, sometimes she links between the two when they cover related topics.
It’s clear to any reader she’s the owner of both sites. It’s not paid advertising but it is promotion. Would search engines like Google consider this artificial link building and penalize the sites?
Both sites are made with a website builder so I’m not sure if she can do ‘do not follow’ links.

It is unlikely that Google would consider this artificial link building as there is not a ton of different sites.
The question would be one of "does Google see the "real" connection (ie in terms of content/context - not links) between the sites"  I expect it probably will, in which case it will not have a detrimental effect.

Thank you for your response. I think Google will when you ask it in terms of content. Even though the primary subjects are different, there are many overlap topics and/or mentions of 'sustainable practices', 'eco-friendly' "bike commuting" "travel" "travel products".
